# How does Notepad++ know to recognize the HTML and CSS in PHP files? Can I do this with PSP files?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to get Notepad++ to recognize PSP (Python Server Pages) files. I've got it to recognize Python (by adding PSP to the `ext=` section), however it doesn't seem to understand that Python is only within the `<% %>` and `<%= %>` sections.

I want it to parse HTML, CSS, Javascript and possibly even PHP (though if I am using PSP, I'd probably stick with that) as well, showing all the colors, etc, that would normally be associated with it.

How do I go about that?

Comment: I think you accidentally hit post before you where finished writing your questi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need to tell it to use the ASP language/lexer. I'm not sure that a user-defined language (see the [NPP Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages) and the documentation) will work due to the dual- (triple-?) mode (HTML vs. PHP/ASP/PSP vs. JS) issues. You may need to add your own custom keywords, or modify the ASP entry in `langs.xml` (buried in AppData or Application Data in your user directory) to use the Python keywords instead of ASP.

Looking at the ["Built-In Languages" info for PHP, etc.](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Built-in_Languages#HTML_.2F_XML_.2F_PHP_.2F_ASP_.2F_JS), it appears that there may be some support for Python (with a typo), but it's noted in a spot where you can put JS/VBS/Python for execution within the browser (and yes, IE DID support VB-based scripting - I've seen at least one web app that used it).